# Getting an error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

getting an error while executing the Rest Assured program

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
```

```
Response response = RestAssured.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");
Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatusCode(), 200);
```

Code
[Maven Dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq4Tv.png)

Comment: Most likely you have mix of conflicting dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: I have added these dependency<dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.3</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Add the pom to your question not as unreadable comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency and remove all other rest assured dependencies.
json-path is already included in rest-assured dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you need schema validator you can add:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you have JDK/JAVA_HOME env variable properly installed. The abouve depedencies should work with JDK 8+

Comment: Getting a new error saying this       "SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
"

Comment: This is warning I believe. You should be able to send request now. You can log it by using this RestAssured.given().log().all().when().get("https://reqres.in/api/users/2");

Comment: You can fix the slf4j warning by adding dependencies :                    
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>